# Making a Grid and Initializing the Squares

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make a basic grid for a crossword and I'm trying to initialize a square to white and its clue number to -1. I don't know where to go from here.

```
public enum TColor { WHITE, BLACK };
public class Square
{
    public TColor Color { set; get; } // Either WHITE or BLACK
    public int Number { set; get; } // Either a clue number or -1 (Note: A BLACK square 
    is always -1)
                                    
    // Initialize a square to WHITE and its clue number to -1 (2 marks)
    pubic Square(TColor Color, int Number)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: public Square() {this.Color=TColor.WHITE; this.Number=-1;} ?

Comment: `TColor` is a bad type name. That's more appropriate for a generic type parameter. A more appropriate name would be `SquareColor` and the values should be `Black` and `White`. You can use bad naming conventions if you want but you just make the code you write inconsistent with standard .NET code and thus confusing.

Comment: Given that nullable value types exist now, it would be better to declare `Number` as type `int?` and use `null` for no clue rather than -1. -1 has been used a lot to represent no value but that's mainly because there wasn't a better option until .NET had already existed for a number of years.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to be able to create a `Square` with other initial values, just initialise the properties and rely on the default constructor:

```cs
public class Square
{
    public TColor Color { set; get; } = TColor.WHITE;
    public int Number { set; get; } = -1;
}
```

If you do want to be able to create an instance with other initial values then you need to provide a constructor for that, so you'd need to provide a parameterless constructor too:

```cs
public class Square
{
    public TColor Color { set; get; } = TColor.WHITE;
    public int Number { set; get; } = -1;

    public Square() { }

    public Square(TColor color, int number)
    {
        Color = color;
        Number = number;
    }
}
```

You might choose to have the parameterless constructor invoke the other constructor instead:

```cs
public class Square
{
    public TColor Color { set; get; }
    public int Number { set; get; }

    public Square() : this(TColor.WHITE, -1) { }

    public Square(TColor color, int number)
    {
        Color = color;
        Number = number;
    }
}
```